# Failed to clone 'MobileBuy/libs/graphql_java_gen'

Tags: android, github, sdk

Hi all I was trying to use the MobileBuy sdk https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android and I am not able to clone the sample application. I have added the ssh keys to my github profile yet I am not able to clone. I have added the screenshot of my problem. here is the link of the sample application https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/tree/master/MobileBuy/sample. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try and update your `knwon_hosts` file:

```
ssh-keygen -R github.com
ssh-keyscan -H -t rsa github.com >> c:\Users\<yourLogin>\.ssh\known_hosts
```

That way, ssh should be able to verify the Host key.

Make sure your `PATH` includes `<git>/usr/bin` (where `ssh` commands are)

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Comment: @vishnumm93 For testing, would it work better with https instead of ssh? `git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`